# How to only display the part of a sub UIView that is just inside its super UIView?

Tags: swift, xcode, swift4, xcode9

How to restrict the visible part of a UIView to the area that is inside of its superview as I draw below? 
I want to apply it to just some of subviews.

[image]

Comment: If you had done a *little* more research, you would have found plenty of answers on this.

Comment: @LinusGeffarth I searched but misunderstand 'cliptobounds', anyway you are right

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to do it for all sub views in a particular view just set the clipsToBounds property of the superview like this.

```
a.clipToBounds = true
```

that will stop any part of any subview being visible outside the superviews bounds.

Comment: TanX, I Just want to do it for some of its subviews

Comment: One simple way would be to add another sub view of the main super view and make it the same size and then add just the ones you want to clip to that and only set its clipToBounds property to true